# Replacing a block of code with a macro (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, macros

I use a block of code frequently when I use the Beamer package.

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\documentclass[handout, 14pt]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

# Start of the block
\def\name{OOP Features}
\section[OOP]{\name}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{}%
\begin{center}%
\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}%
\name
\end{center}%
\end{frame}
\input{a}  
# end of a block
\end{document}
```

I need to replace the block with a single command, `buildchapter,' so I came up with the following macro.

```
\newcommand\buildchapter[3]{
\section[#1]{#2}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{}%
\begin{center}%
\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}%
#2
\end{center}%
\end{frame}
\input{#3} 
}
...
\buildchapter{h}{hello}{a.tex}
```

However, I have errors including ``Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup''. I tried with \def, but the results are the same.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Why a fragile frame?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: I copied the code from an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragile frame option should only be used if it is really necessary. It severely restricts the frame.

In your case, the fragile frame option is not necessary. Fragile content can't be the argument of a macro, so any content which makes it through your macro to the frame can't be fragile and thus does not need a fragile frame.

```
\documentclass[handout, 14pt]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{a.tex}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}


\newcommand\buildchapter[3]{
\section[#1]{#2}
\begin{frame}%
\begin{center}%
\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}%
\insertsection
\end{center}%
\end{frame}
\input{#3} 
}

\begin{document}
    
\buildchapter{h}{hello}{a.tex}
    
\end{document}
```